# What LED color temperature should I choose？

Tags: led, light

I am planning to start a new company, but I don't have much funds. I am thinking about what led light should I choose as the light in the office area. Can it achieve the two conditions of being cheap and suitable for office?

Comment: Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on *electronics design*.

Comment: The color temperature of you lighting will be the least of your problems / challenges when starting a company. If you already need to consult "random punters" on the internet for this then I fear you might need to educate yourself more on what is involved in starting a company.

Comment: Maybe think about what goes on in the office. If you're doing marketing and design or food science you might prefer an environment that allows colors to be perceived more accurately. If you're doing engineering work, in my experience anyway, a lot of light of any color temperature is more valuable than any particular color temperature.  Low flicker may be a factor, especially in a 50Hz region.

Answer (score 3):

When you start a company you should write a spec. called a Mission Statement to define all your expectations and then your measurable objectives.  The same idea is for lighting to define Lumen intensity at some height, colour temperature and CRI for ease of reading papers and screens and a NTE (not to exceed) budget for hardware and installation.

4500K~5000K CRI>=90 True daylight is my preference

Answer (score 2):

Most people like LED "warm white" at home, but I prefer a "cool white" (more blue) at work. It helps people wake up, especially in winter in high latitudes.
Color temperatures [here](https://www.aisledlight.com/color-temperature-led-lighting/), for example.